# How to use dropdownlist icon (= 3 lines)?

Tags: html, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms, angular-material-6

```
 <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
    </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-grid dropdown-menu-mat" style="display: block;">
   <li id="editEventName" ><a><span class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></span>Edit User</a></li>
   <li id="mapEvent"  >
   <a><span class="fas fa-user-plus"></span>Assign User</a>
   </li>           
   </ul>             
 </mat-cell>                  
</ng-container>
```

How to Use Icon of (= 3 lines i am unable to show 3 lines) fro dropdownlist. in table for delete and edit opertaion

Comment: It's called a hamburger icon :)

Comment: @Martijn ok thank you.but how to use it in angular material?

Answer (score 0):

It's explained at https://material.angular.io/components/menu/examples and a running example is given in following [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/angular/lvoggqveygd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmenu-icons-example.ts)

To obtain the hamburger icon, simply replace the icon of the trigger button as follows:

```
<mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the Font-Awesome cdn link below, and copy cdn past to the HTML header section.

https://cdnjs.com/libraries/font-awesome

2. Go to the Font-Awesome, search "bars" and select one. Copy the icon(<i.../i>) link past where you need it.

https://fontawesome.com/icons